# a uniform data structure that can represent an ndarray with various size along a given axis

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, computer-vision, numpy-ndarray

I can use the following code to generate three dimensional array.

```
import numpy as np
x1 = np.random.rand(8,9,10)
```

In some scenarios, the studied data set (or array) have various length along the axis 0, In other words. A subset may be of shape (8, 9, 10), and another subset maybe of shape (7,9,10).  All these subsets are of the same size along the second and the third axis. If I still want to represent the whole data set using the same data structure, how to achieve this goal?

Comment: A numpy array necessarily has the same number of items along a given dimension.

Comment: Why do these arrays have to be in the same `numpy` array?  Why not just have a list of them?  In other words, what do you hope to do with  the array structure that you can't do with a list?

Comment: a specific example would help illustrate what you're up to. "the studied data set" is being vague AF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use awkward-array:
https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward-1.0

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import awkward as ak

>>> numpy_arrays = [np.random.rand(8,9,10), np.random.rand(7,9,10)]
>>> irregular_array = ak.Array(numpy_arrays)
>>> irregular_array
<Array [[[ ... ]]] type='var * 9 * 10 * int64'>
```